# Windows phone 8 C#: How to parse JSON Array of Array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, json

Can any body tell me how I parse this type of json in windows phone 8 using `Newtonsoft.Json` dll?

```
[
   [
      {
         "condition_id":"1",
         "condition_name":"Type 1 Diebetics"
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "condition_id":"2",
         "condition_name":"Type 2 dypatise"
      }
   ]
]
Thanks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do that for retrieving condition name.

```
JArray jsonarray = JArray.Parse("Your Json String Here");
var dict = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Convert.ToString(jsonarray));
foreach (var obj in dict[0])
{
  Debug.WriteLine(obj["condition_name"]);
}
```

Hope it will help you,